# In how many ways can we partition $k$ (distinct) items into $n$ blocks so that we have $k_i$ blocks of size $i$ for each $i$?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition, stirling-numbers

This question originates from Problem 139 at https://bogart.openmathbooks.org/ctgd/s3-2-partitions.html, which I located a solution file at

https://github.com/OpenDiscreteMath/ibl-combinatorics/blob/update-bogart/ComboNoteswSolutions11-6-04.pdf

The solution, however, appears to contain some serious typos:

[image: Solution to Problem 139]

In particular, as I understand it, all "$n$" in the Solution section should be replaced by "$k$", resulting in what I think is the correct solution:

\begin{align*}
\frac{k!}{\prod_{i=1}^k(i!)^{k_i}k_i!}
\end{align*}

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Any notation that involves $k_k$ (the number of blocks of maximum potential size $k$ so equal to $0$ if $n >1$ or $1$ if $n=k$) is asking for problems.

Comment: Indeed I think even the question per se has a typo: instead of

"The sequence $k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_n$ is called the type vector of the partition",

it should rather be

"The sequence $k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_k$ is called the type vector of the partition"

Comment: As a test, try $k=10$ and $n=2$ with $k_4=k_6=1$ and the other $k_i=0$.  The answer should be ${10 \choose 4}$ and your corrected notation gives this while the original fails badly

Comment: I too managed to get confused in my original comment:  $k_k = 1$ is only possible if $n=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is correct; a proof is given e.g. by Andrews in [*The Theory of Partitions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sp7z9sK7RNkC&q=theorem+13.2), Theorem 13.2:

> [image: screenshot of theorem statement]

Comment: Nice, and thanks!